# bash script: Getting "division by 0" trying to declare associative array

Tags: arrays, bash

I've got the following (seemingly) weird problem: I'm writing on a setup script to symlink or copy files for a Wordpress installation depending on which system it is being deployed on. To be able to iterate over a list of files to copy around I've declared an associative array. The following code snippet causes bash to give me a "division by 0" error:

```
declare -a files
files["conf/${SYSTEM}/.htaccess"]=".htaccess"
files["conf/${SYSTEM}/wp-config.php"]="wp-config.php"
```

Here is the entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function usage_and_exit {
    echo "Usage: $0 <vm|stage|live> [copy]"
    echo
    echo "Append 'copy' in order to copy files instead of symlinking them."
    echo "    Example: $0 stage copy"
    echo "    take config files from the stage directory and copy them to the"
    echo "    document root."
    exit 1
}

if [ "${PWD##*/}" != "scripts" ]; then
    echo "This script has to be run from inside <DOCUMENT_ROOT>/scripts."
    usage_and_exit
fi

## -------------------------------
##  check command line args
## -------------------------------

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    usage_and_exit
fi

case "$1" in
    vm)
        ;;
    stage)
        ;;
    live)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unrecognised argument: $1"
        usage_and_exit
        ;;
esac

COMMAND="ln -s"
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    case "$2" in
        copy)
            COMMAND="cp"
            ;;

        *)
            echo "Unrecognised argument: $2"
            usage_and_exit
            ;;
    esac
fi

## -------------------------------
##  MAIN
## -------------------------------

SYSTEM=$1
cd ..

# array of files to symlink or copy; LHS is source, RHS destination
declare -a files
files["conf/${SYSTEM}/.htaccess"]=".htaccess"
files["conf/${SYSTEM}/wp-config.php"]="wp-config.php"

for file in "${!files[@]}"
do
    # delete destination first if it's a symlink
    if [ -L ${files[$file]} ]; then
        echo "rm: ${files[$file]}"
        rm -f ${files[$file]}
    fi

    echo "${COMMAND}: $file -> ${files[$file]}"
    $COMMAND $file ${files[$file]}
done
```

Can somebody point out to me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Associative arrays are declared with `-A`, not `-a`.

Comment: Do you actually *need* an associative array? The destination directory is the same so you could just join the strings

Comment: @ruakh I haven't got the -A option for declare:

    $ declare -h
    -bash: declare: -h: invalid option
    declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

I'm on macOS but I don't think this should make a difference as bash is GNU on all systems...

Comment: @arco444 This is very likely to be extended in the future with different, custom paths. So, this is not really an option.

Comment: @tigrefurry: Associative arrays are a relatively recent addition to Bash, so it's not shocking that you don't have them. You'll need to either upgrade your Bash version or do without this feature.

Comment: @ruakh: That turned out to be the problem, indeed. I've upgraded my bash version (macOS Sierra ships with v3.2.57) with Homebrew to v4.4.12. It's working as expected now. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ruakh provided the right hint in the comments section to the question. It is indeed `declare -A`, not `declare -a`. The reason I was trying a small "a" was that bash gave me an error when I first tried it with a capital one, so I assumed it had to be a typo in the how-to I was following.

In the end the culprit turned out to be an outdated version of bash that comes with macOS (Sierra): 3.2.57. The reason is the updated conditions in the GPL for bash >= v4. ([See this blog post.](https://blog.bennycornelissen.nl/bash-4-x-on-osx-the-bash-that-apple-wont-ship/)) [This answer on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx) provided me with the right solution.